# Changing between iterating forward and reverse

Tags: c++, list, iterator, reverse

I have a animation class which stores the frames in a std::list, the header file declares a iterator, I increment the iterator using time. My animations are working fine until I try to reverse the animation (from the current position), I can't decrement the iterator (bidirectional huh?). I've thought about storing a reverse iterator too but can't find a nice way to switch between the two.

How can I seamlessly switch between forward iterating and reverse iterating (without starting from the beginning of the std::list).

Comment: Have you considered using a `std::vector` instead? Lists are useful if you have many inserts and deletes all over the place, but with animations, I don't think this will be the case.

Comment: Impossible to answer without some example code as to what is not working.  `std::list` iterators are bidirectional, and `--` works on them.

Comment: I was originally using a vector but changed to list to see if this would fix my problem (because the iterator is supposedly bidirectional).

Comment: `vector` and `list` both have bidirectional iterators, and decrementing them should work. What does your code look like, and what error do you get?

Comment: Post relevant code snippet and error that you get. `list<T>::iterator` is bidirectional. Do you move iterator within the list boundaries?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What do you mean "I can't decrement the iterator"?

On my Visual C++ 2010, this works:

```
std::list<int> l;
l.push_back(1);
l.push_back(2);
l.push_back(3);

auto i = l.end();
while (i != l.begin()) {
    --i;
    std::cout << *i << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to decrement a list iterator; without seeing your code, and the error it produces, I can't guess what's going wrong there.

However, it might be more convenient to represent an animation as a generic iterator range:

```
template <typename ForwardIterator>
void animate(ForwardIterator start, ForwardIterator end)
{
    for (; start != end; ++start) {
        start->display();
    }
}

std::vector<frame> animation = ...;
animate(animation.begin(), animation.end());   // play forwards
animate(animation.rbegin(), animation.rend()); // play backwards
```